# clarifai iOS demo not working on Xcode 8 and iOS 10

Tags: ios, image, clarifai

I'm trying to get this demo to work on the simulator using Xcode 8 but I get stuck at "Recognizing" when I upload the image. Can anyone help with debugging this ? I have also reached out to Clarifai for comments.

Code downloaded from here:
https://github.com/Clarifai/clarifai-ios